# Normal.dotm being used by a different process?

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office-automation, word-automation

I have an application that:

1. Copies a file
2. Pastes the copy with a new name
3. Modifies it
4. Saves it

This has been working fine, but then today, I've been getting this error:

> Normal was being edited by another Word session.  If you save this
>   document with the original name, you will overwrite any changes made
>   in the other session.  Do you want to save the document using the
>   original name anyway?

And this is the file location of "Normal.dotm".  I've never seen this file and am not manually accessing this file in any of my code.

> C:\Documents and Settings\MyUserName\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm

I'm running old code that has worked fine in the past, and I reset my computer, so I don't think any of my processes are screwing this up.  What could be causing this?  It seems like something happened externally to cause this problem, but I could be wrong.  I'm genuinely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You might get this save message when you edit the styles or margin settings of the document.

Refer this
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-HA010030756.aspx

I suppress this message in my application because we set some settings for Word when the document opens up

```
 foreach (Word.Template template in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Templates)
 {
    switch (template.Name.ToLower())
    {
        case "normal.dotm":                       
            template.Saved = true;
            break;
    }
  }
```

I have noticed that if you have outlook opened it locks the normal.dotm file so check if your outlook is editing your normal.dotm file